# Is it possible to pass html into a Scrolling Table in Gojs?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gojs

I'm working on go js. I have two div and I need to connect the contents of them with links. Therefore I just saw a Scrolling-Table concept in Gojs by which we can connect each row of left table with the rows of right table.

Now I need to pass an html div into rows for both left and right tables. 
This html div contains a switch button together with a asp dropdown.

It is possible to pass such html content in each row of Scrolling Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because GoJS wants to be able to render to canvas and to SVG and to other targets, one cannot embed any HTML in a diagram.  You'll need to implement it yourself using GoJS **GraphObject**s.  Read http://gojs.net/intro about the basic **Shape**s and **Panel**s.  For examples of how the various kinds of predefined buttons are implemented, see http://gojs.net/latest/extensions/Buttons.js.